# I need to remove a segment till a delimiter ");" after two or three lines of a search keyword in file using perl script

Tags: regex, perl

Iam trying to remove a test segment frequently occurs in a file. I have a matching keyword let suppose

```
FIND_WORD(---------
            -----------
             -----------);
```

is terminating after 2 or 3 lines at " `);`" but i need to remove next few lines also till "`);`"

I am using

```
if ($line =~ m/FIND_WORD/) {return 0;}
```

which removes one line
I need to remove till "`);`"

Comment: Rahul i edited the question for formatting, please check if it correct as for your scenario.

Comment: Do you want to read the file in and write out another but without these lines?

Comment: I am reading from one file and writing to another but i need without those lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this is exactly what the flip-flop operator is for.

```
while (<>) {
  print unless /FIND_WORD\(/ .. /\);/;
}
```

From [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is
>   bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma)
>   operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator
>   maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine
>   that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false.
>   Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the
>   right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false
>   again.

See [this recent GeekUni blog post](http://blog.geekuni.com/2016/03/perl-flip-flop.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multi-line matching. You will need to slurp the whole file into a variable and then substitute that.

```
$all_lines =~ s/FIND_WORD.*?\)\;//sg;
```

This matches from FIND_WORD to the nearest ");" and deletes it.

Comment: You might want to double-check that regex. I don't think that `.?` does what you think it does. You might mean `.*?` or `.+?` instead.

Comment: @DaveCross Thanks - I was looking for non-greedy matching. Fixed now.